HTTP request canceled
well I had this code in my  angular component
sub: Subscription;

this.sub = this.notificationService
                .getNotificationByUser(reqbody).subscribe(res => {});

ngOnDestroy(){
this.sub ? this.sub.unsubscribe() : '';
}

so the problem is, this http request is getting canceled and my portal keeps loading for more than 10 mins after that this api is again getting called with 404 response
but when i did the following
    destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();
 this.notificationService
                .getNotificationByUser(reqbody).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
                .subscribe(resp => {});
ngOnDestroy() {
this.destroy$.next(true);
}

this api directly returns 404 status without taking long to respond and without prolonged loading
Any idea why is this happening?
Please help

I hope this link might help you understand the subscribe/unsubscribe hell => https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/8404545

where do you call getNotificationByUser? is it inside ngOnInit?

Not directly inside ngOnInit but this is present in nested functions .

can you explain like I'm 5? the stack overflow byzantine conversations related to this topic is not helping me what I'm looking for.
